Updating API using formik in react js
I have a formik already populated with user data I need when he clicks update to update if he did any change to the form and send it to the API.
I'm missing something not sure what, I already used it with a register form.
Changed different parts of formik and tried to look online on formik's docs and google but no luck.
Here is my code....
import { FunctionComponent, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../context/userContext";
import { NavigateFunction, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import InputField from "../components/InputField";
import { Form, Formik, FormikHelpers } from "formik";
import { User } from "../interfaces/User";
import {
  initialValuesObj,
  onSubmitObj,
  validationSchemaObj,
} from "../misc/registerFunction";
import { updateUser } from "../services/usersService";
import { reactToastifySuccess } from "../misc/reactToastify";

interface ProfileProps {}

const Profile: FunctionComponent<ProfileProps> = () => {
  const navigate: NavigateFunction = useNavigate();
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [userEdit, setUserEdit] = useState<User>(user || ({} as User));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) navigate("/login");

    if (user) setUserEdit(user);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <>
      <h5 className="display-5 my-2">Profile - {user?.name.first}</h5>
      {/* {user && ( */}
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">
            Full Name: {user?.name.first} "{user?.name.middle}"{" "}
            {user?.name.last}
          </h5>
          <p className="card-text">{user?.email}</p>
          <p className="card-text">{user?.phone}</p>
          <p className="card-text">{user?.address.city}</p>
          <p className="card-text">{user?.address.state}</p>
          <p className="card-text">{user?.address.country}</p>
          <p className="card-text">{user?.address.zip}</p>
        </div>
        <Formik
          initialValues={user ? user : initialValuesObj}
          validationSchema={validationSchemaObj}
          enableReinitialize={true}
          onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
            console.log(values);
            // actions.setValues(values);

            actions.setSubmitting(false);
            if (user?._id) {
              updateUser(user._id, {
                ...values,
                isBusiness: user.isBusiness,
              })
                .then((res) => {
                  if (res) {
                    setUser(res.data);
                    navigate("/profile");
                    reactToastifySuccess("User updated successfully");
                  } else {
                    reactToastifySuccess("User update failed");
                  }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  reactToastifySuccess("User update failed");
                  console.log(error);
                });
            }
            // onSubmitObj(values, setUser, navigate);
          }}
        >
          {({ values, handleReset, isValid, dirty, handleSubmit }) => (
            <Form className="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-center">
              <InputField
                label="First Name"
                name="name.first"
                value={values.name.first}
              />
              <InputField
                label="Middle Name"
                name="name.middle"
                value={values.name.middle}
              />
              <InputField
                label="Last Name"
                name="name.last"
                value={values.name.last}
              />
              <InputField label="Phone" name="phone" value={values.phone} />
              <InputField
                label="Email Address"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                value={values.email}
              />
              <InputField
                label="Image URL"
                name="image.url"
                value={values.image.url}
              />
              <InputField
                label="Image alt"
                name="image.alt"
                value={values.image.alt}
              />
              <InputField
                label="State"
                name="address.state"
                value={values.address.state}
              />
              <InputField
                label="Country"
                name="address.country"
                value={values.address.country}
              />
              <InputField
                label="City"
                name="address.city"
                value={values.address.city}
              />
              <InputField
                label="Street"
                name="address.street"
                value={values.address.street}
              />
              <InputField
                label="Houst Number"
                name="address.houseNumber"
                value={values.address.houseNumber}
              />
              <InputField
                label="Zip Code"
                name="address.zip"
                value={values.address.zip}
              />
              <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center w-100">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-primary mt-3 col-5 me-2"
                  type="submit"
                >
                  Update
                </button>
                <button
                  type="reset"
                  className="btn btn-warning mt-3 p-2 col-5"
                  onClick={() => {
                    handleReset();
                  }}
                >
                  Reset
                </button>
              </div>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </div>
      {/* )} */}
    </>
  );
};

export default Profile;


You can call Formik's resetForm with the user data then use the isDirty property to tell if anything has changed https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#dirty-boolean

Thank you.
Other errors were also involved.
